# Settings different GPU as default display in multi GPU ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

Used previously posted threads from this forum to set up my 1030 card as the display card 
done the following steps:

```
lspci | grep VGA

17:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e04 (rev a1)
65:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e04 (rev a1)
b3:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
```

then in

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
changed to 
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID              "PCI:b3:0:0"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection
```

connected the HDMI cable to the card, restarted, and got no display.
Ideas? (Ubuntu 18.04, the other two are 2080TI)

<
here is the full `xorg.conf`

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 418.88

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:b3:00.0"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

When using Nvidia's default xconf, I see that the BusID of the 2080 is

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:101:0:0"
EndSection
```

Which is not at all the output of
  lspci | grep VGA

When I'm restarting I loss display, and have to enter recovery mode and create a new xconf